# How do I clone a conda environment and simultaneously add packages without dependency conflicts?

Tags: conda

How do I create an exact copy (ie. a clone) of a conda environment and *at the same time* add new packages to the newly cloned environment. This is to avoid package dependency conflicts which may be created when installing packages later, [as indicated in a tip here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands).

The following one-liner doesn’t appear to work because `clone` expects 0 arguments:

```
conda create -n newenv --clone oldenv newpkg1 newpkg2 newpkg3
```

Comment: If you want to do this, the best bet is to export the environment dependencies to a YAML file (`conda env export` I believe) and edit the resulting file to add your new dependencies, then `conda env create` to make a new environment.

Comment: I have the same problem. However, when I try the suggested solution, conda spits out dependency errors. The environment is too complex to do manually. Not sure how to solve this; just adding new dependencies in the .yml file doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Matt perhaps try exporting a less precisely defined version of the env by adding a `--no-builds` or a `--from-history` flag to `conda env export`.